# How to add extra column in the INTO section of SQL Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-trigger

How to add an extra column (say column_2) in the below INTO section of my code along with my Column_1. I assume we can do that by adding comma (,) and just add column_2 (like this INTO :new.Column_1, new.column_2). I'm missing something?

```
create or replace trigger trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT SEQUENCE_NUMBER.NEXTVAL
INTO :new.Column_1
FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: What did you try? What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to confirm whether you are right (or wrong). I hope you got the answer during the past 6 hours. If not, here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id       number,
  3     datum    date);

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_test;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select seq_test.nextval, sysdate
  6      into :new.id, :new.datum
  7      from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (id) values (-1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID DATUM
---------- -------------------
         1 21.06.2019 21:54:08

SQL>
```